# Assigning custom roles on user creation in Azure AD

Tags: azure

Azure lets you define custom roles for an AD tenant by modifying the manifest:

```
 "appRoles": [
{
  "allowedMemberTypes": [
    "User"
  ],
  "description": "Admins can manage roles and perform all actions.",
  "displayName": "Global Admin",
  "id": "some GUID",
  "isEnabled": true,
  "value": "Admin"
}, ... ],
```

and, according to the [msdn azure graph api reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ad/graph/api/entity-and-complex-type-reference#AppRoleAssignmentEntity), you can use the graph api to programmatically assign a user to a custom role. But I'm having trouble getting this to work where I'm creating a new user and trying to assign a role using `AppRoleAssignment`. I think the problem is that I need to define the user's ID, but that is defined by Azure once the user is created, so does that mean it's impossible to assign a user to a role at the point of creation and it can only be done once the user has been added to the directory ? Below is a snippet of the code I'm using to assign the role.

```
var appRoleAssignment = new AppRoleAssignment();
            appRoleAssignment.Id = Guid.Parse("some-guid-here");
            appRoleAssignment.ResourceId = Guid.Parse(clientId);
            appRoleAssignment.PrincipalId = ??? // what should go here for a user that hasn't been created yet ?
```

Comment: Did you try upload the manifest after modify it?

Comment: @Lily - I did..I can assign roles and update a user and get a successful response back. I can try to re-assign the same role to the same user and I get a bad request response back - which is the correct behaviour and proves the assignment worked. But when getting the users data there is no role in the AppRoleAssignments field, it always shows 0.

Comment: Ah it's ok I found it - it's in the ClaimsPrincipal..but perhaps you can explain why role assignments don't appear in the AppRoleAssignment field of the user profile but in the ClaimsPrinciple ?

Comment: Not AppRoleAssignment, AppRoleAssignment contains all application role assignments for a user. But you want to get role information in application, the role is user, do you?  I am confused, I see `getting the users data there is no role...`  what you want is add role to application or add role to user? if you want user role from application, you need query app infor

Comment: @lily, you're confused, I'm confused, everyone's confused..and the confusion on my part came from the "appRoles" field in the manifest. So in the manifest if you set the allowed member type to just "User", but not "Application", then the role will not appear in the "appRoleAssignment" field of the ActiveDirectoryClient.Users class, because as you say the appRoleAssignment refers to the role of the app not the user. If there was another field like "User role assignment" - in the User field then it would be clearer, because user and application roles are both defined together in the manifest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clear appRoleAssignments,appRoleAssignedTo will let us understand the relationships of user role, app role, user, application.

1) an application can be assigned to an User as **app role**. Open the 
User option of an application named "ADlinglitest":
[image]

Call:`https://graph.windows.net/Tenantid/users/lingliad01@lingliad.onmicrosoft.com/appRoleAssignments?api-version=1.5` get the result:
[image]

Call:`https://graph.windows.net/tenantid/servicePrincipals/servicePrincipalsobjectid/appRoleAssignedTo?api-version=1.5`, you will see 3 user which are assigned.

[image]

2)an user can be assigned to an application as **user role**, group, application also can be assigned to application as a role.

```
"appRoles": [
{
"allowedMemberTypes": [
    "User"
  ],
  "description": "Admins can manage roles and perform all actions.",
  "displayName": "Global Admin",
  "id": "7c93906c-71fa-4e5b-b1da-21b073d298fd",
  "isEnabled": true,
  "value": "Admin"
}
]
```

Call:`https://graph.windows.net/tanantid/servicePrincipals/serviceprincipalobjectid/appRoles?api-version=1.5` get the result:
[image]

if you dont know objectid, call `https://graph.windows.net/tanantid/servicePrincipals?api-version=1.5` to get the SP objectid of your application.

3) as you mentioned "User role assignment", actually it lacks a method `userRoleAssignedTo`, if the user is assigned to an application as user role, we could query the application infor through `userRoleAssignedTo`.
It is indeed easily let people feel confused.

Comment: thanks @Lily_, I appreciate your help, this is all very clear now. I don't see the "users" tab in the portal view for my app, is it for some kind of specific types of app only ?

Comment: ya, sometimes the user option disappeared, refresh the application page more times.

Answer (score 0):

Without the identifier the role cannot be assigned. Objects and identifiers get created when user is created.

Comment: Q, so apparently this is like windows active directory, where you have to create a user first then assign a role to them..fair enough but it means you have to implement a transaction wrapper over your graph code - if a user is created successfully but the assignment of a role fails - then the user has to be deleted to prevent orphaned users..

Comment: Whats wrong with - if a user exists assign a role, if it doesn't create and assign a role ?

Comment: nothing, just it requires two operations, if the second fails then you have to "roll back" the user..actually i tried this today, and azure does make it easy to in a safe way. But while we're on the subject, i keep failing to assign the role..im using the service principle object id returned by the client, there is only one..what should else should i be aware of ?

Answer (score 0):

I dont find the C# code about assign a user to application role in azure official documents. I only can see the Powershell and Rest api method.

Powershell:

`New-AzureRmRoleAssignment -ObjectId <application id> -RoleDefinitionName <role name in quotes> -Scope <subscription id>`

REST API:

PATCH -- https://graph.windows.net/tenantid/application/clientid?api-version=1.5

BODY should like this,the id is the objectid of the user:

```
{
  “appRoles”: [

    {     

  “allowedMemberTypes”: [       
  “User”, “Application”     
  ],     
  “description”: “Dentists may create, update and delete patient’s health records”,   
  “displayName”: “Dentist”,     
  “id”: “31952ade-a03c-414c-8340-2f11e9099106″,     
  “isEnabled”: true,     
  “value”: “dentist”   

     }
]
```

Rest api in C# example:

```
    AuthenticationContext ac =
                    new AuthenticationContext("https://login.microsoftonline.com/tenantid");
                AuthenticationResult ar =
                    ac.AcquireToken("https://graph.windows.net",
                                    new ClientCredential(Constants.ClientId, Constants.ClientSecret));

                string result = string.Empty;
                HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
                httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization =
                    new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", ar.AccessToken);
                HttpResponseMessage response =
                    httpClient.PostAsync("https://graph.windows.net/tenantid/application/clientid?api-version=1.5","json/body").Result;
if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    result = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
                }
                Console.WriteLine(result);
                Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: there may be no official c# code but it does work using UpdateAsync(), which is just a wrapper for a POST. Everything works fine for me now, but the confusion comes from a) the manifest includes "user" and "application" roles in the same field b) the AppRoleAssignment class can be added to a User not just an app and succesfully update the role of the User c) having said all that, the returned AppRoleAssignment class of a user in the IUser class doesn't show User roles, but only application roles